# Angular 7 - How do I force API calls to wait for HTTPInterceptor to finish before making additional API calls?

Tags: angular, api, bearer-token, angular-http-interceptors

In Angular 7, I'm using a HttpInterceptor to get a Bearer token that needs to be added as a header to any API calls (ex. getOnLoadData()). Whenever I try to make the getOnLoadData() call, the interceptor is called successfully, but the token value keeps returning as null because it gets executed before the interceptor is completed.

I'm trying to use async/await to make the call asynchronous, but it looks like I'm doing it incorrectly and I can't seem to figure out where the fault is. I'm fairly new to Angular. I've been searched quite a few different examples, but can't figure it out.

**HTTPInterceptor**

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return from(this.handle(req, next))
  }

  async handle(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const result = await this.getBearerToken();

    const tokenizedReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${result}`
      }
    })

    return next.handle(tokenizedReq).toPromise();
  }
```

**API Call**

```
async getOnLoadData() {
    await this.tokenInterceptorService.getBearerToken()

    return this.httpClient.get('/initialloaddata', {
      headers
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a data stream that starts with the fetch of the auth token and ends with a patched request if it's needed.

```js
public intercept(request: HttpRequest<void>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<void>> {
    return from(this.getBearerToken()).pipe(
        switchMap(token =>
            iif(
                () => !token,
                of(request),
                of(
                    request.clone({
                        setHeaders: {
                            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                        },
                    }),
                ),
            ),
        ),
        switchMap(clonedRequest => next.handle(clonedRequest)),
    );
}
```

`from` knows how to transform a promise to an observable data stream. so it solves it and passes the result (token) to the pipe. then we have `switchMap` which check whether token is present. If no (iif operator) it returns the original request with no changes (2nd argument of iif), if yes then it returns a clone with the desired header. After that we have one more `switchMap` that simply switches the data stream to the `next.handler`.

Comment: Any chance you could explain this a little bit more please? I don't think I'm following what exactly this is trying to do.

Comment: sure, `from` knows how to transform a promise to an observable data stream. so it solves it and passes the result (token) to the pipe. then we have `switchMap` which check whether token is present. If no (iif operator) it returns the original request with no changes (2nd argument of iif), if yes then it returns a clone with the desired header. After that we have one more `switchMap` that simply switches the data stream to the `next.handler`.

Comment: I gave this a shot and I'm getting the token successfully, but getOnLoadData() still doesn't get the token value. It looks like they're being called at the same time and getOnLoadData() completed first but the token is set as "Bearer null" and doesn't wait for the interceptor to finish.

Comment: if you want first to wait `getOnLoadData` and only then call `getBearerToken` you need concat instead of from: `concat(this.getOnLoadData(), this.getBearerToken()).pipe(skip(1))`, and `skip` to ignore the value from the `getOnLoadData`.

Comment: Is there a more generic way to do this? getOnLoadData() isn't the only API call that I'm making. I would actually need every API call that I'm making to wait for the token to be received.

Comment: Ah, `getOnLoadData` doesn't belong to the token. Its request should have the token. Then the original answer is what you need. An interceptor applies to all http calls. You need to register it with providers and then simply call `this.httpClient.get('/initialloaddata')` without the 2nd parameter with headers, the interceptor will add the header if `this.getBearerToken` returned it.